How can I add a json information to a Twillio Studio flow, using Python?
I'm a beginner to twilio and it's services, and needed a simple call_forwarding flow. However, the outgoing number changes every few hours (and that change is not regular). There is a Excel file, already input in Python and converted to JSON information with the name of the person and the number that should be called at all times (I use an API to keep the information accurate).
I can't correctly set a function using Python to input this JSON information on the flow.
My flow in studio is "Call incoming -> function widget to grab the phy_name and phy_number -> Read a sample message 'redirecting to {{phy_name}}' -> outgoing call to {{phy_number}}"
Code looks like:
json_info = json.dumps(info) #This variable is something like: '{"phy_name": "Bob Ross", "phy_number": "+1111111111111"}'


account_sid = 'ACXXXXX'
auth_token = 'acXXXXX'
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

function = client.serverless \
                 .v1 \
                 .services('ZSXXXXXX') \
                 .functions \
                 .create(friendly_name='MyFirstTry')

print(function.sid)

I am having troubles configuring the function in Python, since I have no idea on how to access files or program using JS.

This code will create a new function. Are you planning to run this function every time when the Excel file changes? If so, then you won't need to fetch the data from the API since you already know the redirect number when you execute the script

You could also use a Studio flow that uses the Function widget to fetch the current redirect number. But then you'd need to implement the Function in JavaScript as this is the only supported langauge

Or you can host your own REST API that exposes the current phone number in your favorite language on your own tech stack. In this case, however, you need to use the Make HTTP Request Widget.

I believe that the third choice is the one I'll try to implement! Thank you for all the insights.
